# Python. Не видит значение переменной при выводе функции

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции

Только начинаю разбираться в Питоне, наткнулся на небольшую проблему.

```
def minimum(a, b):
  a = int(input('Type number a: '))
  b = int(input('Type number b: '))

  if a > b:
      print (b)
  elif a == b:
      print ('a equals to b')
  else:
      print (a)

minimum(a,b)
```

Когда запускаю код, выдаёт ошибку:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "test.py", line 12, in 
>       minimum(a, b)
>   NameError: name 'a' is not defined

Питон версии `3.5.1`.
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При вызове функции

```
minimum(a,b)
```

питон не находит переменную а так как в коде её нет. Та что находится в функции не считается.

```
  a = int(input('Type number a: '))
  b = int(input('Type number b: '))
```

нужно вынести из функции

Comment: Спасибо, усвоил.

Answer (score 5):

По коду видно, что переменные **a** и **b** функция будет получать из пользовательского ввода (функция **input**). Следовательно не имеет смысла передавать эти переменные как аргументы функции. Вот пример :

```
def minimum():
  a = int(input('Type number a: '))
  b = int(input('Type number b: '))

  if a > b:
      print (b)
  elif a == b:
      print ('a equals to b')
  else:
      print (a)

minimum()
```

Если вам не нужно получать эти переменные из пользовательского ввода, то не нужно использовать функцию **input**. А переменные **a** и **b** нужно передать вручную. Вот пример :

```
def minimum(a, b):

  if a > b:
      print (b)
  elif a == b:
      print ('a equals to b')
  else:
      print (a)

minimum(5, 1)
```

Конкретно ошибка, которую Вам выдает, указывает на то, что переменной, которую Вы пытаетесь использовать, еще не существует.

```
minimum(a, b)
```

При вызове функции нет переменной ни **a** ни **b**. Они будут определены только локально, внутри этой функции, уже после ее вызова.

Answer (score 0):

перед использованием переменных нужно им задать значение а так для питона это просто символ а не переменная
 введите сюда код

```
a=0
b=0
def minimum(a, b):
  a = int(input('Type number a: '))
  b = int(input('Type number b: '))

  if a > b:
      print (b)
  elif a == b:
      print ('a equals to b')
  else:
      print (a)

minimum(a,b)
```